# Switching Views Back and Forth

Tags: ios, view

I am trying to switch views in my application. I have the following code to take me from the Main View to the first level view:

```
-(IBAction)levelOneButton
{
    levelOneView *testView = [[levelOneView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    testView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:testView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Which works GREAT! Then the Code to take me to the next level is the exact same but slightly different!

```
-(IBAction)nextLevelButton
{
    LevelTwoView *levelTwo = [[LevelTwoView alloc] init];
    levelTwo.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:levelTwo animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Now when I want to go back to the Main menu from here is where the issue occurs. I have the following code which only dismisses the level2 and shows level1 again.

```
- (IBAction)goBackButton {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Like I said when this code is used it just releases the current view and takes you back to the last view instead of taking you back to the main menu. After realizing it was not working I tried the following code to take me back to the main menu.

```
- (IBAction)goBackButton {
    ViewController *mainMenu = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    mainMenu.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:mainMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When this code is run, I get presented with a black screen.

My question remains how may I go back to the view ViewController? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this when dismissing the second level view controller.

```
[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController]  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```